# Microsoft/Codeplex Windows 7 USB Tool; Does it include the ISOs? How to verify the hashes?

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation, iso-image

I recently used the [Windows USB Tool](https://wudt.codeplex.com/#) from Codeplex and I noticed that there are some new ISOs in its folder.  I didn't recall having the option to download ISOs, and nothing in the help page or the main page suggests that the tool downloads ISOs for you.

I didn't think Microsoft freely gave away it's ISOs, but I uncovered that fact while reseaching that.  However, I could not uncover the ISOs nor their MD5 hashes.  I found some SHA-1 hashes [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8a49c3c-3bec-476a-8888-85c5c49bf97e/sha1-for-security-release-iso-image?forum=w7itprosecurity) though, but I don't know the veracity of this site/posting, since I can't determine it's officiality.

- Does this tool normally download ISOs?
- Is it a default installation option, or did I select it somewhere?
- How do I verify they are legitimate, untampered with ISOs?
- How do I know what flavor image they are (VL, retail, OEM)
- How do I know what key is needed for them?
- How do I know if these ISOs are used by the tool, or if it uses the one I select? (I think it used the one I selected during my last use, but I'd like to know)
- Is there some documentation or man page that I missed somewhere that explains all this already?

The tool appears to have created this folder/directory and these files:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have asked 7 separate questions.  Can you reduce the scope of this question?  [Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062) can be downloaded by anyone for free.  You should only worry about which version it is (Home,Professional, Ultimate, etc.).  If you don't have a key to Windows 7 then it is moot.  You don't need to use this tool to make the installation disk, there are better tools, for that job.

Comment: That is very odd. Also last time I checked W7UDDT was available on Technet, so they changed something...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does sort of gives away free Windows ISOs, but that's since Windows 8 AFAIK.

I don't see how would the ISOs be downloaded by that tool, since the step one of the tool requires you to browse for an ISO, that is, specifying a path for that. If it acts as some sort of ISO download manager I suppose it will simply give you a list instead:

[image]

AFAIK the tool is merely an installation DVD/USB creator for ISO(s) you got from Microsoft Store.

So I bet you just downloaded those ISOs from *somewhere* yourself but have forgotten about that?

Comment: That's logical but I use MSDN and these arent MSDN names.